# Erro ao inserir registro, último valor de indice possível já usado

Tags: mysql

Estou com um erro ao tentar inserir um registro alguém sabe resolver.

Segue a mensagem de erro:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `local`.`tab_evento` (`id`) VALUES ('18446744073709551616');

ERROR 1264: 1264: Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `local`.`tab_evento` (`id`) VALUES ('18446744073709551616')
```

**Edit**:  O id é um tipo **BigInt(11) unsigned**, já tentei alterar ele para **bigint(20) unsigned** e continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: por questões de otimização, não seria interessante usar um ID composto? pelo que parece esta tabela trabalha com eventos, você teria outros campos que possam compor esta chave primária e torna-la composta? algo como data?

Comment: @Delfino mesmo usando a data como parte da chave primária o problema continua, da erro, é que o campo id não incrementa mais da o mesmo erro

Comment: realmente vc terá que alterar o banco e passar a usar uma procedure para autoincrementar a chave composta, zerando o contador sequencial sempre que ele estourar, e ter um segundo campo que irá contar este estouro ou pelo período ou simplesmente pelo overflow, acho que isso aqui pode lhe ajudar; http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120156/2766598

Comment: @Delfino esse caso de criar procedure para autoincrementar não resolve porque o numero incrementado eu tenho, ele só não consegue inseri-lo porque é maior do que o campo suporta, se eu zerar o contador eu fico com problemas no relacionamento entre outra tabela

Comment: sério que você tem 18446744073709551616 registros em sua tabela??? fiquei impressionado. do que se trata?

Answer (score 0):

O valor que você está inserindo é maior do que o valor máximo suportado pelo tipo definido a coluna.

Pode consultar os máximos tamanhos para cada campo: [integer-types.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

Uma alternativa para seu problema, é mudar o tipo do campo para **varchar** e definir com um tamanho maior, porém terá de mudar a forma com que acontece o **auto-increment**.

Comment: nao, meu ultimo registro na tabela é 18446744073709551615

Comment: ele é um BIGINT

Comment: Mesmo sendo bigint unsigned continua sendo menor que o valor que você tenta inserir. bigint usigned -> (2*(2^63))-1

Comment: já sei que o valor maximo suportado no BigInt é https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html mas e agora? faço o que, travou tudo aqui

Comment: Teria um exemplo de código fonte de como ficaria o auto-increment esse caso uma pk sendo varchar e como ficaria os relacionamentos que já existem nessa tabela tem como manter?

Comment: O controle do auto-increment teria que ser feito por código usando transaction (todo bom framework já cuida disso para você), quanto as fk você teria de refatorar o banco. Bom, como primeira solução eu vejo isso, espere ver se não aparece alguém com uma ideia melhor.

Comment: tem um framework que gerencia o auto-increment do MySql? Qual?

Answer (score 0):

Para se solucionar tal problema será necessário usar uma chave primária composta, e controlar o autoincremento através de uma trigger, portanto não será mais automático no próprio campo.

Com base no script abaixo, você poderá ampliar as regras de mudança dos períodos conforme sua necessidade e assim ajustar o id para 1 a cada novo período, mas veja que a contagem do período está manual, para torna-la automática será necessário ampliar o código do trigger para que se baseie em uma terceira tabela de parametrização.

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tab_confere_evento`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_confere_evento` (
`id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `evento_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `evento_periodo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tab_evento`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_evento` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `periodo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `evento` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Tabela para guardar os logs de modulos abertos pelo usuário' ;

--
-- Triggers `tab_evento`
--
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `prx_periodo_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `tab_evento`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
    set new.id=(select ifnull((select max(prx_id)+1 from tab_event where periodo=new.periodo),1));
end
//
DELIMITER ;

--
-- Indexes for table `tab_confere_evento`
--
ALTER TABLE `tab_confere_evento`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`evento_periodo`), ADD KEY `idx_evento_id` (`evento_id`,`evento_periodo`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tab_evento`
--
ALTER TABLE `tab_evento`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`periodo`), ADD KEY `id` (`id`), ADD KEY `periodo` (`periodo`);
```